# Impulse and momentum (max velocity condition)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Why  maximum subsequent velocity is attained when the block comes to rest relative to top of the hill?
Please refer to the  diagram below.

[image: pls refer image attached]

Answer (score 1):

You can argue that while moving up the hill, the block exerts a normal interaction force on the hill having a component in the rightwards direction. This increases the velocity of the hill in rightward direction.

While the block is moving down the hill from the other side, the normal force now has a component directed leftward which is now slowing the hill.

Thus a maxima in velocity of the hill will be achieved at the instant when the block is at the hilltop.

I hope that answered your question.

Comment: But why are at  that moment(i.e hill top) both the bodies will move together i.e they are at rest relative to each other  ?

Comment: I don't think we can comment on it without knowing the value of h. You can possibly write the equations of momentum conservation in horizontal direction and the conservation of energy and find out the interval of h ( in terms of the provided parameters ) for which they move together at the hilltop